# How to properly configure cas-dc

Tags: environments, els-cas

I am trying to write an article for an elsevier journal using their double column layout. Unfortunately whatever I try, the class

`\documentclass{cas-dc}`

gives me the following error:

> `Undefined control sequence.\__hook begindocument ...idth =\textwidth \bibsep=0pt\gdef \bibfont {\fonts... \begin{document}`

I am following the documentation here
https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/doc/elsdoc-cas.pdf

But even the MWE

```
\documentclass{cas-dc}

\title{elsevier double column}
\author{meetaig}
\date{October 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Does not compile. I also tried to do this on overleaf to make sure it is not just some misconfiguration of my own tex environment. Is there just a bug in the class file? Or is there anything missing from the documentation that is important to include?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: You'll have to load `\usepackage{natbib}`, so that `\bibsep` is defined. Also it may be easier to start a new project from the CAS DC template here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elseviers-cas-latex-double-column-template/hhzpymgjmxfk

Comment: Thanks a lot! that solution works for me :)

Comment: Somewhat duplicate of [cas-sc class does not print author list, affiliations, abstract and keywords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488510/cas-sc-class-does-not-print-author-list-affiliations-abstract-and-keywords).  To answer the question in the title: you don't :)

Answer (score 0):

As @imnothere said, the problem here was to not include `natbib`

this snippet works

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\title[ mode = title ] {this is a title}
\author{meetaig}
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```